# Blob to Base64 in javascript not returning anything from FileReader

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, base64, filereader

I am using `FileReader` in typescript to convert a blob to a base64 image that will then be displayed in the template of my application.

```
  adaptResultToBase64(res: Blob): string {
    let imageToDisplay : string | ArrayBuffer | null = '';

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function () {
      imageToDisplay = reader.result;
      return imageToDisplay;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(res);

    return imageToDisplay;
  }
```

Whilst the data logged inside the `read.onloadend` function displays the base64 string I cannot pass it out of the function.

I have tried adding a callback but where it is called elsewhere doesn't return anything but an empty string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? (rhetorical) [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: A very good explanation of all things async, but it turns out poor explanations and documentation on the specific thing I needed was more my issue!

Answer (score 2):

### Please check this code

```html
<input type="file" id="file">
<button id="click">click</button>
```

```
let data: string | ArrayBuffer;

document.getElementById('file').onchange = function (e: Event) {
  let files: FileList | null = (<HTMLInputElement>e.target).files;

  let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) {
    console.log(e.target.result);
    data = e.target.result;
  };
  if (files.length > 0) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(files?.[0]);
  }
};

document.getElementById('click').onclick = function () {
  console.log(data); // result if present otherwise null is returned
};
```

### Using a separate method view. The `return` value is a `Promise`.

```
function adaptResultToBase64(res: Blob): Promise<string> {
    let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            resolve(reader.result as string);
        }
        reader.onerror = () => {
            reject("Error reading file.");
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(res);
    })
}
```

### To get the result

```
adaptResultToBase64(/* Blob value */)
    .then(resp => console.log(resp))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

#### See here for specifics on `Promise`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
[learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)

Comment: This is good, but I'm not calling the function in the DOM. I'm getting the base64 from another file and using it elsewhere.

Comment: Well, I think I understand you. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75226084/20851740)

Answer (score 0):

The basic result I needed and did not realise that the `reader.onload` is actually a callback for `read.readAsDataUrl` and finishes everything inside it async.

```
adaptResultToBase64(res:Blob){

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function () {
      
    // Was missing code here that needed to be called asynchronously. 
    
    adapterToNewObject(reader.result.toString())

    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(res);

  }
}
```

I was performing this in Angular so for anyone else who runs into this problem here it is using Angular syntax:

In your class:

```
export class Component {

adaptedResult:Result


 getBase64() {
    this.http.get().subscribe((result: Blob) => {

        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => { 

          this.adaptedResult =  this.adapter(reader.result) // Assign or use  reader.result value, this is an example of using an adapter function.
        };
    
        reader.readAsDataURL(result);
      });
  }



 adapter(base64:string){
  return {
   name:'image',
   image:base64'
   }
 }

}
```